# VMWare ESXi No internet access on VMs

Tags: ip, internet

Created a new VM on my brand new vmware ESXi using vspehre client 5.5 and assigned an IP to the VM but no internet access.
I'm pretty sure both gateway and netmask are correct.

What am I missing?

UPDATE: There is no network access at all. When I ping the main server IP, It says Network is Unreachable.

UPDATE2: [Here is the content of ifcfg-eth0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djSWv.jpg)

UPDATE3: [vSwitch Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KPyg.jpg)

Comment: No ip is assigned to this NIC. can you paste the contents of your ifcfg-eth0 script?

Comment: The original post has been updated with the contents of ifcfg-eth0

Comment: Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability. Also use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" rather than posting screenshots. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Comment: How's your vSwitch setup?

Comment: @Chopper3 vSwitch screenshot added to the original post.

Comment: This looks like a home setup?

Comment: `I'm pretty sure both gateway and netmask are correct` - It's not enough to be pretty sure. You have to be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your eth0 is in DOWN state, so you need to start it. Run

```
ifup eth0
```

and see the output. Maybe you'll should fix your ifcfg-eth0 file. 
For network autostart on VM boot you can change

```
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

And don't forget to uncomment your GATEWAY string after all.

Comment: Thank you so much Anton. Your solution solved my problem.